# Gracefully Handle Datatime in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have the following code that gives me this error

ERROR: invalid value "test" for "YYYY"

Code:

```
select * from
     (select i.uuid as t1uid,
             m3.short_id as short_id_start,
             m.text_value as original_date,
             TO_TIMESTAMP( trim ( substring(m.text_value, 1, 19)), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS' ) as tms 
      from item i
      inner join metadatavalue m on i.uuid = m.dspace_object_id
      inner join metadatafieldregistry m2 on m.metadata_field_id = m2.metadata_field_id
      inner join metadataschemaregistry m3 on m2.metadata_schema_id = m3.metadata_schema_id
      and m3.short_id ='interaction'
      and m2."element" = 'startts') t1
   join
     (select i.uuid as t2uid,
             m3.short_id as short_id_fail,
             m.text_value as success_status
      from item i
      inner join metadatavalue m on i.uuid = m.dspace_object_id
      inner join metadatafieldregistry m2 on m.metadata_field_id = m2.metadata_field_id
      inner join metadataschemaregistry m3 on m2.metadata_schema_id = m3.metadata_schema_id
      and m3.short_id ='interaction'
      and m2."element" = 'status'
      and m.text_value = 'SUCCESS') t2 on t1.t1uid = t2.t2uid
   join
     (select i.uuid as t3uid,
             m3.short_id as short_id_start_endt,
             TO_TIMESTAMP( trim ( substring(m.text_value, 1, 19)), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS' )as enddate
      from item i
      inner join metadatavalue m on i.uuid = m.dspace_object_id
      inner join metadatafieldregistry m2 on m.metadata_field_id = m2.metadata_field_id
      inner join metadataschemaregistry m3 on m2.metadata_schema_id = m3.metadata_schema_id
      and m3.short_id ='interaction'
      and m2."element" = 'endts') t3 on t3.t3uid = t2.t2uid
   left join
     (select m.text_value as "Protocollo",
             i.uuid as t4uid
      from item i
      inner join metadatavalue m on i.uuid = m.dspace_object_id
      inner join metadatafieldregistry m2 on m.metadata_field_id = m2.metadata_field_id
      inner join metadataschemaregistry m3 on m2.metadata_schema_id = m3.metadata_schema_id
      where m3.short_id ='interaction'
        and m2."element" = 'protocol' ) t4 on t4.t4uid = t3.t3uid
   left join
     (select i.uuid as t5uid,
             m2.qualifier as qualifier_sender,
             m.text_value as "Sender"
      from item i
      inner join metadatavalue m on i.uuid = m.dspace_object_id
      inner join metadatafieldregistry m2 on m.metadata_field_id = m2.metadata_field_id
      inner join metadataschemaregistry m3 on m2.metadata_schema_id = m3.metadata_schema_id
      where m3.short_id ='interaction'
        and m2."element" = 'application'
        and m2.qualifier in ('sender') ) as t5 on t1.t1uid = t5.t5uid
   left join
     (select i.uuid as t6uid,
             m2.qualifier as qualifier_receiver,
             m.text_value as "Receiver"
      from item i
      inner join metadatavalue m on i.uuid = m.dspace_object_id
      inner join metadatafieldregistry m2 on m.metadata_field_id = m2.metadata_field_id
      inner join metadataschemaregistry m3 on m2.metadata_schema_id = m3.metadata_schema_id
      where m3.short_id ='interaction'
        and m2."element" = 'application'
        and m2.qualifier in ('receiver') ) 
        as t6 on t1.t1uid = t6.t6uid
        where tms > TO_TIMESTAMP('2023-05-18T00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
```

the last line:
 `where tms > TO_TIMESTAMP('2023-05-18T00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')`
is the problem (without it the code works)

but when i do:

```
create table public.timeline_success as 
... 
same code of before without the last where condition.
```

```
select * from public.timeline_fail t1 
where t1.tms > TO_TIMESTAMP('2023-05-18T00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
```

the code works ... how to resolve this?

Comment: The error message is suggesting that there is data in the calculated tms column that it doesn't recognise as a valid timestamp. Try removing the final WHERE statement and then examining the data in the tms column to identify the problem data

Comment: Run the following to identify rows where the first four characters after leading spaces in `tmetadatavalue.text_value` aren't numeric :`SELECT * FROM metadatavalue WHERE text_value !~ '^ *\d{4}'`.

Comment: select * from public.timeline_fail t1 
where t1.tms > TO_TIMESTAMP('2023-05-18T00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
works normally

Comment: the problem is in the full query with the full joins, finishing the query until t1 and putting the where condiction it works normally too

Comment: In your large SELECT statement in your question you are not querying public.timeline_fail and tms is a calculated column within a subquery. I am therefore confused when in your comment you give a completely different query against a different table/column and say that it works - how is that relevant to your initial question? Have you tried either of the suggestions that you have been given?

Comment: Can you give an example of tms column when you executed without that predicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line, `where tms > TO_TIMESTAMP('2023-05-18T00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')`, is not the cause of the problem but is instead the triggering condition that exposes the problem. Without that line, the only column referenced from `t1` is `t1uid` and that is only needed for joining to other tables. PostgreSQL skips evaluating the rest of `t1`'s select list because those values don't contribute to the final result set. When that final condition is included, then `tms` must be evaluated.

Resolve the problem either by modifying the offending data, or by modifying the query such that invalid data in the column is gracefully handled.

The following demonstrates the described behavior:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (ID integer PRIMARY KEY, test_value text);

CREATE TABLE table2 (ID integer PRIMARY KEY, test_label text);

INSERT INTO table1(id, test_value)
VALUES (1, 'FAIL-05-26T01:00:00'),
       (2, '2023-05-27T02:00:00');

INSERT INTO table2(id, test_label)
VALUES (2, 'Pass');

SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT id AS t1id,
               TO_TIMESTAMP(test_value, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') AS tms
          FROM table1) t1
  JOIN (SELECT id AS t2id,
               test_label
          FROM table2) t2 ON t1.t1id = t2.t2id
-- WHERE t1.tms > '2023-05-27'::timestamp;
```

Running the above returns:

| t1id | tms | t2id | test_label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2023-05-27 02:00:00-04 | 2 | Pass |

Running with the `WHERE` clause uncommented results in the following exception:

```
ERROR:  Value must be an integer.invalid value "FAIL" for "YYYY" 

ERROR:  invalid value "FAIL" for "YYYY"
SQL state: 22007
Detail: Value must be an integer.
```

The following output from `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE)` gives some insight into what is happening. Note that raw column values are returned from the sequential scans. Operations on those values aren't evaluated until needed.

```
Hash Join  (cost=38.58..67.79 rows=1270 width=48) (actual time=0.027..0.029 rows=1 loops=1)
  Output: table1.id, to_timestamp(table1.test_value, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'::text), table2.id, table2.test_label
  Inner Unique: true
  Hash Cond: (table1.id = table2.id)
  ->  Seq Scan on public.table1  (cost=0.00..22.70 rows=1270 width=36) (actual time=0.008..0.009 rows=2 loops=1)
        Output: table1.id, table1.test_value
  ->  Hash  (cost=22.70..22.70 rows=1270 width=36) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=1 loops=1)
        Output: table2.id, table2.test_label
        Buckets: 2048  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 17kB
        ->  Seq Scan on public.table2  (cost=0.00..22.70 rows=1270 width=36) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=1)
              Output: table2.id, table2.test_label
Planning Time: 0.110 ms
Execution Time: 0.050 ms
```

One approach to gracefully handling text that has an invalid timestamp format is to create a function that returns the value of a successful conversion and `NULL` if an exception occurs. The following function supports that approach.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION try_to_timestamp(ts_string text, ts_format text) RETURNS timestamptz
LANGUAGE plpgsql
STABLE LEAKPROOF STRICT PARALLEL SAFE COST 1 AS
$FUNC$
BEGIN
  RETURN TO_TIMESTAMP(ts_string, ts_format);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN NULL;
END
$FUNC$;
```

After replacing the call to `TO_TIMESTAMP` with a call to `try_to_timestamp`, the query no longer fails when an invalid timestamp string is encountered.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT id AS t1id,
               try_to_timestamp(test_value, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') AS tms
          FROM table1) t1
  JOIN (SELECT id AS t2id,
               test_label
          FROM table2) t2 ON t1.t1id = t2.t2id
WHERE t1.tms > '2023-05-27'::timestamp;
```

| t1id | tms | t2id | test_label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2023-05-27 02:00:00-04 | 2 | Pass |

Comment: Can you explain how to gracefully handle not date time types that can cause the problem?

Comment: One option is to call `to_timestamp` only when `test_value` conforms to the expected format and otherwise return `NULL`; e.g., `CASE WHEN test_value ~ '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T([01]+[\d])|(2[0-3])(:([0-5][0-9])){2}' THEN to_timestamp(test_value, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') END AS tms`. Instead of returning `NULL`, a special timestamp value could also be returned. The best approach will depend on how the query results will be used.

Comment: please can you make a query for that? i can't understand in the comment

Comment: i try to add where 
        to_char(t1.tms,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') ~ '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T([01]+[\d])|(2[0-3])(:([0-5][0-9])){2}' but always  ERROR: invalid value "test" for "YYYY"

Comment: Not in the `WHERE` clause, in the select list. The goal is to avoid an invalid conversion. Replacing `TO_TIMESTAMP( trim ( substring(m.text_value, 1, 19)), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS' )` in the first subquery with `TO_TIMESTAMP((REGEXP_MATCH(m.text_value, '^(\d{4}-((0\d)|(1[0-2]))-((01)|([[12]\d])|(3[01]))T(([01]\d)|(2[0-3]))(:[0-5]\d){2})'))[1], 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS')` will avoid most invalid conversions; however, it doesn't prevent invalid days for a month; e.g., 2023-02-30.

Comment: Another approach is to create a function that returns the value from calling `TO_TIMESTAMP` or `NULL` if an exception occurs. One of the advantages of this approach is that it preserves all of the capabilities of `TO_TIMESTAMP` with minimal effort from the developer.